# how configure babel to import css

Tags: javascript, css, babeljs

How make babel to **import .css to .js** without webpack use because in my project there is no webpack and i want to configure **via .babelrc**;

It this moment i havent this config file yet;

Preinstalled babel-watcher and  babel-packages: babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3 babel-loader@latest
with i use without .babelrc

```
import '../js/pagination.js';
import '../css/pagination.css';

export default class Pagination extends React.Component{
```

At this moment i get the next error

```
     Failed to load module script: The server 
     responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of 
     "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is 
     enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Comment: this will help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-import-css